# Two-pane graphical file manager for Linux remembering the editor position

Tags: linux, file-management, gui

Are there any [orthodox file managers for *nix](http://alternativeto.net/software/krusader/?platform=linux) that remember the cursor position in the edited files (and ideally have the list of recently edited files accessible)?

Krusader doesn't, and it's [no longer maintained](https://github.com/KDE/krusader/pull/1).

Double Commander doesn't, and there has been [no interest in that feature request](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3400).

Midnight Commander does remember the editor position, but it's console-based.

While preferring free solutions, I'd be happy to pay for such an OFM if one existed. Other features I'm looking for:

- ideally open the edited file in the same window, so I can switch to it quickly with Win+1 (my file manager is the first in the launcher)
- archive support (.TAR, .GZ, .ZIP, .RAR)
- list of recently used or favorite directories (Krusader) and files
- ability to drop the current file into the command line (MC)
- good keyboard shortcuts (NDN), ideally customizable
- ideally open source, and ideally maintained on GitHub, not SourceForge or some other obscure repository

But really, remembering the editor position seems to be so overlooked, that I haven't found any Linux OFM that does this. Perhaps it's better to ditch the internal editor and launch an external one that remembers details about the recently used files.

Comment: Should it be a graphical file manager, or would console-oriented file managers be welcome as well? Any specific features you need except fot the editor part (and the obvious copy/move/delete)? Would a payed variant be acceptable, or must it be free?

Comment: @Izzy: I've updated the question. I'd be happy to pay for such an OFM if one existed. Basically I'm trying to replace the excellent [NDN](http://ndn.muxe.com/download/), which hasn't seen an update since 2010.

Comment: OK, and you've just included what I had in mind (Midnight Commander). Mind-reading? :) Still: What features are must-haves – could you do another [edit] and include that? People might find it a bit broad otherwise ;)